# path may not be null or empty string. path='null'?

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

```
rootProject.name = 'video'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native-gradle-plugin/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())

include ':@react-native-firebase_analytics'
project(':@react-native-firebase_analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics/android')


if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
  include(":ReactAndroid")
  project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid");
  include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
  project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid/hermes-engine");
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiCrs.png)

I am updating my react native project from 0.70 to 0.73 latest verison in that process iam unable to run my react native application and facing this error  Settings file 'D:\etv2\player\android\settings.gradle' line: 12

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'video'.

> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

I need solution for this error and RN application to be run smoothly without any errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project is not detecting your path correctly. Are you sure you wrote your project path correctly? Alternatively, could you try using "D:/etv2/player/android /settings.gradle" instead of "D:\etv2\player\android \settings.gradle"?

Comment: Yes path is perfectly correct but in RN 0.70 i didnt faced this issue after updating RN version iam facing this issue